# Mensagem "A fila de edições sugeridas está completa"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Fui tentar editar um post e o link de editar estava desabilitido. Esta foi a mensagem que apareceu:

> A fila de edições sugeridas está completa

Fila completa!? Hã!?

Eu proponho um texto melhor:

> A fila de edições sugeridas está **cheia**

Comment: Podes indicar qual o "post" para poder visualizar essa mensagem?